# How to validate dates of different formats with Jquery

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I have a requirement to validate `start-date < end-date`, but the date formats changes based on the regional settings.
User can change region of site at any time when user changes to different date formats by validation fails.

I get error if the format is of **19-2-1**

```
function getFormattedDate(datestr) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;  
  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

//date format for all regions (`mm-dd-yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyy`, `d mm yyyy`, `mm dd yyyy`, `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd.mm.yyyy`, `mm.dd.yyyy`)

```
if (isNaN(StartDateEnfant.valueOf()) || isNaN(OData__EndDateEnfant.valueOf())) {
   StartDateEnfant = new Date(startDate.replace(/(\d{2})[- /.](\d{2})[- /.](\d+)/, "$2/$1/$3"));
   OData__EndDateEnfant = new Date(endDate.replace(/(\d{2})[- /.](\d{2})[- /.](\d+)/, "$2/$1/$3"));
}
```

I get wrong validation if start date is 3.1.2019(jan 3 2019) and end date if 10.1.2019 ( jan 10 2019) but it takes as sep 10 2019 which is wrong

Comment: How does user change region settings, is it some configuration in your system?

Comment: Is 19-2-1 first of February or second of January? How should the script know what is meant?

Comment: You need to know the region settings. How will you know if the format is mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: Behind the scenes, you should just set a permanent date format, but just show the "regional" format to the user.

Comment: User have option to change regional settings using share point regional settings page, i cant set permanent date format date picker automatically shows date format as per region upon selecting date. i can get the regional setting selected by user but will not be knowing date formats for that region